# Freewall grid in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, freewalljs

Hello guys I need help with this plugin. I've got these plugin settings:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");;
    wall.reset({
        selector: '.brick',
        animate: true,
        cellW: 300,
        cellH: 'auto',
        onResize: function() {
            wall.fitWidth();
            wall.fillHoles();
        }
    });
    wall.fitWidth();
});
```

And my css:

```
.brick {
    width: 300px;
}
```

On mobile screen block's vanishe like this, what is wrong??? Here is my picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lrzZ.jpg

I've tried fixing this with reset and etc. Nothing worked. How can I solve this problem?